# "Unknown name" when calling DirectoryEntry.DeleteTree

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to delete AD users and groups with PowerShell, however I'm getting an "Unknown name" exception.

Code:

```
function RemoveADEntry($dn) {
    $entry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$dn")
    $entry.DeleteTree()
}
```

Result:

```
Exception calling "DeleteTree" with "0" argument(s): "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"
At :line:9 char:18
+   $entry.DeleteTree <<<< ()
```

Calling Get-Member on $entry doesn't return any methods, only properties.

Comment: Does $entry.psbase.DeleteTree() work?

Comment: @dhorn post it as an answer so lzm can accept it. To OP: Is there a specific reason why you don't use the active directory cmdlets?

Comment: @Tom Ignorance of said cmdlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
$entry.psbase.DeleteTree()
```